# Playing a sound in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, audio

So I'm developing an app for android and iOS in visual studio with Xamarin forms and I need a button to play a sound but I have a problem, when I press the button I got the: "system.argumentnullexception has been thrown" and that I dont have the "stream" value but I dont really see where is missing.
Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace PrototypeII
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        Button panic;
        Button settings;
        Button relax;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            BackgroundColor = Color.LightGray;

            panic = new Button
            {
                Margin = new Thickness(10),
                FontSize = 30,
                BackgroundColor = Color.Red,
                Text = "Panic",
                TextColor = Color.Black,
            };

            panic.Clicked += panic_clicked;

            relax = new Button
            {
                Margin = new Thickness(10),
                FontSize = 30,
                BackgroundColor = Color.GreenYellow,
                Text = "Tchill",
                TextColor = Color.Black,
            };

            settings = new Button
            {
                Margin = new Thickness(10),
                FontSize = 20,
                BackgroundColor = Color.GreenYellow,
                Text = "..."
            };

            var Grid = new Grid
            {
                Margin = new Thickness(20, 40),

                ColumnDefinitions =
                {
                    new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) },
                    new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) },
                    new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) },
                },

                RowDefinitions =
                {
                    new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(0.5, GridUnitType.Star)},
                    new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)},
                    new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)},
                    new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)},
                    new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)},
                }



            };

            Grid.Children.Add(settings, 3, 0);

            Grid.Children.Add(panic, 0, 1);
            Grid.SetColumnSpan(panic, 2);

            Grid.Children.Add(relax, 2, 2);
            Grid.SetColumnSpan(relax, 2);

            Content = Grid;
        }

        private void panic_clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var assembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;

            Stream audioStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("PrototypeII.123.mp3");

            var audio = Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.Current;

            audio.Load(audioStream);

            audio.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

If you could tell me how to solve this or... an easier way idk... please tell me.

Comment: `audioStream` is null - that means it was unable to load your mp3 resource

Comment: isn't enough if I put my audio file in the resources file for iOS and in the assets file for android????

Comment: You are loading it as an embedded resource from your shared assembly, so you need to place it there.  Or change the way you are loading it

Comment: Forgive me but... How do I place the sound file in the shared assembly?

Comment: just add the file to your .NET Standard project and set the build action to Embedded Resource

Comment: I did it mate! Thanks a lot.